# My js file has exceeded the length

Tags: lightning-web-components

Error: value too long for field: source maximum length is:131072
Getting above error while deploying Lwc through VScode.
Can anyone please help me for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error above which you are getting is because your JS file has more than 131,072 bytes Size. As mentioned in official [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_components_javascript)

> A component’s JavaScript file can have a maximum file size of 128 KB (131,072 bytes).

The workaround would be to create child components and split the code accordingly, or else move some of the JS code and put that code into a Static Resource so that you can refer to it.

Comment: Also, you can have multiple JS files in a single component.